# save choice after reloading page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple tab gallary from w3school.
You see some images, and when the user click on an image, this image got shownunder.
I make an image as a default shown image.
I want to make that when the user change the image (click on another image) and reload the page or close the browser. then open the site again without loosing the choosen image.
Example:
User choose image number 3, then closes the browser or reload the page, then when the user open the page again, the choosen image will be image number 3(not the default one).

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}


document.getElementById("defaultimage").click();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
  opacity: 0.8; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container */
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

/* Expanding image text */
#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Closable button inside the expanded image */
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Tabbed Image Gallery</h2>
  <p>Click on the images below:</p>
</div>

<!-- The four columns -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/209" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);" id="defaultimage">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/2092" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/2021" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/2097" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know about: [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)?

Comment: I have NO idea, am new with javascript.

Comment: @NNL993 localStorage will not be persistent when you close the browser...

Comment: @LelioFaieta there is no way that can happen, maybe in your browser localStorage clears when you close browser? Check out your add-on or your browser config list.

Comment: @LelioFaieta local storage persists between browser sessions in all browsers. The only exception is for private/incognito modes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: @DavePritlove from the document you quoted (first rows): _for the duration of the page session (as long as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores)_ when you close the browser the page session is gone...

Comment: No, that's session storage not local storage, local storage is persistent "localStorage does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.".  You could prove this yourself  in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible you will want to store the image src in local storage which saves even if the browser closes. Local storage is similar to cookies but be warned user can delete localstorage from developer tools in any browser.

```
         var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
 // variables have to be global so they can be accessed anywhere not just inside the function
 if (localStorage.getItem("image_src") != null && localStorage.getItem("image_alt") != null) {
   //image set
   myFunction(localStorage.getItem("image_src"), localStorage.getItem("image_alt"));
 } else {
   // image is not set
 }

 function myFunction(src, alt) {
   expandImg.src = src;
   imgText.innerHTML = alt;
   expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
 }

 function setImage(src, alt) {
   localStorage.setItem("image_src", src);
   localStorage.setItem("image_alt", alt);
 }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
This w3schools page states that local storage saves after browser is closed

This jsfiddle works but you cannot get the last saved image since the src always links to a random everytime but this is what I could come up with
https://jsfiddle.net/0rvs6d53/14/

Comment: no, this doesn't fully solve OP issue. When you close the browser localStorage is gone. You have to use cookies or a backend to keep it after browser is closed

Comment: Its not working. https://codepen.io/saliem-antoun/pen/xxYZQyx  Axazexz player.

Comment: Lelio! Am using shopify. making a similar way to give the user an avatar image. do you have any idea how to save this image for the user account?

Comment: @LelioFaieta no, this is fully OP solution for THIS question, do you read title of question? By the way, in MY browser, local storage not clearing even if browser was closed, maybe you are using old version or something?

Comment: I'am using a new version, but thank you anyway!